# Redis Exceptions with ServiceStack

Tags: redis, servicestack

I periodically I get these exceptions:

RedisResponseException
Unexpected reply: +OK, sPort: 60957, LastCommand:

It seems to happen when lots of activity occurs simultaneously. Using even the latest Amazon ElastiCache server, as well as local Mac & Ubuntu flavors.

Other errors occur to but this is the most common. Is there some gotcha with Redis in terms of config settings etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using PooledRedisClientManager or BasicRedisClientManager?

I got a lot of *Unexpected reply* whith BasicRedisClientManager

Comment: I wasn't specifying a manager at all ^_^ and using the Redis client just the same as the in memory client - essentially a singleton. In hindsight I can see why that might be a problem. Not sure if I copied an incorrect example or assumed it would work the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error (Unexpected reply) on a multi-threaded Azure Worker Role.

Solution:
The ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient is not Thread safe.
On multithreaded applications you need to create a new insance of the RedisClient for each thread!

```
var myRedisClient = new RedisClient(accessKey);
```

...or use the client manager as fvoncina said. But I didn´t use it so far.

Comment: The docs on ServiceStack.Redis is quite clear that you need to use one of the [ThreadSafe Client Managers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-client-managers)